# Using TabPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, pane, graphicscontext

I'm switching from using a flowpane to a tabpane. I have no idea how to.
I want to use a canvas and a pane within the tabpane is this possible?
Below is my code without all the styling etc.

```
 public View(TabPane root) {
    this.root = root;

    tab1 = new Tab();
    root.getTabs().add(tab1);

    tab2 = new Tab();
    root.getTabs().add(tab2);

    ui = new Pane();

    canvas = new Canvas(600,600);
    //gc is graphics context
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    //this is where the problem is??
    //i have no idea how to add ui and canvas to my tab1
    tab1.getChildren().addAll(ui, canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Tab`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html) is not a subclass of `Pane`, so it has no `getChildren()` method.

Instead, it has a [`content` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#contentProperty) whose value is the node displayed in the tab (note there is only one node in a tab).

So you can display the canvas in the tab with

```
tab1.setContent(canvas);
```

and of course if you have two things to display, you would put them in some other container and set the content of the tab to the container:

```
VBox vbox = new VBox(ui, canvas);
tab1.setContent(vbox);
```